# Parsing c# TimeSpan without days and hours

Tags: c#, .net, timespan

I have a time span string like this: `20 min 49 sec`
I would like to parse it `TimeSpan` instance, however I'm having bad time with it.

From the docs, it states that days and hours properties have to be set, but in my case I don't have them and I'd like to know if it's possible to make create such format where I can omit those values.

Comment: Please, share what have you tried

Comment: date and time are not mandatory: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_TimeSpan__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

Comment: Try this: `TimeSpan.ParseExact(input, @"%m' min '%s' sec'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - works like a charm - please post as answer so you I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To parse **that *exact*** string, you'd use this expression:

```
TimeSpan.ParseExact(input, @"%m' min '%s' sec'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Basically, you treat every text other than where the numbers are as literal delimiters, specified using the `'xxx'` syntax.

If you think you might need to handle both `min` and `mins` as well as `sec` and `secs`, you need to use the overload with multiple formats:

```
string[] formats = new[]
{
    "%m' min '%s' sec'",
    "%m' mins '%s' sec'",
    "%m' min '%s' secs'",
    "%m' mins '%s' secs'"
};
TimeSpan.ParseExact(input, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

And contrary to what you think the documentation states, you don't have to specify days or hours at all, this is perfectly legal:

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(45);
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parseexact?view=net-8.0

```
  var intervalString = "17:14:48.153";
  var format = @"h\:mm\:ss\.fff";
  var result = TimeSpan.ParseExact(intervalString, format);
```

More examples on their site.